# Find last value in a time series over multiple items in Spotfire

Tags: time-series, spotfire

I am attempting to find the last entry on a time series in one data table and place that value on another data table.

I have:

```
Entity  Value  Date
1       1      01/1990
1       2      02/1990
2       1      02/1990
2       3      03/1990
```

The function would pull out 2 for entity 1 and 3 for entity 2.

I have attempted the use of a last function but have not had any success.

```
Last([Gas]) Over (Intersect([Entity], AllPrevious([C.Month/Year])))
```

I am a bit new to Spotfire and would appreciate any help that could be provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values are sequential and thus get larger as the date increases, use `Max()` instead.

```
Max([Gas]) Over (Intersect([Entity], AllPrevious([Date])))
```

Otherwise, you may have to find the last date, and associate the value. I assume the `[Date]` field is of a Date datatype, but if not, it should be.

```
case when [Date] = max([Date]) over (Intersect([Entity],AllPrevious([Date]))) then [Date] end
```

Comment: Thanks @scsimon, I cant seem to get the code strip you posted to work? I believe something is wrong with the ALLPrevious but being unfamiliar I am having trouble debugging. Could you help me out?

Comment: I had an error in the second formula. It's been corrected @geop

Comment: case when ([C.Month/Year] = max([C.Month/Year]) over (Intersect([Entity],AllPrevious([C.Month/Year])))) then [C.Month/Year] end

Comment: ok? I don't know what your column names are, but you listed it as [Date] in your sample data

Comment: The above runs but gives me C.Month/Year as an output?

Comment: I see, I think what I am looking for is Max([Date]) at the end also. Thanks @scsimon

Comment: aggregating the Boolean result would depend on where you are using this, but if that is what you want I am glad it works. It may also be the column [Value] based on your OP but you listed column names outside of the sample data....

Comment: I think I spoke to early, it appears that this gives the max date of all entities and not per entity....any ideas?

Comment: Aside from my last comment? No. I can't determine what the actual column names are since they don't match the sample data...